# How can I get msvc to embed c++ source into pdbs for easy debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging a crashdump for using Visual Studio, I notice that it prints a message about looking in the pdb to see if the source file it is looking for is there:

> Searching for documents embedded in the symbol file.

How can I get MSBuild/msvc to include source files when generating PDBs?

Our current solution is to [embed a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/language-specification-1) in the source file that downloads the relevant source from a given URL. However, that is giving us trouble because many machines we debug on don't have access to the source URLs and also the URLs for old builds may become invalid if a project moves.

[image: .cpp not found: Searching for documents embedded in the symbol file]

Comment: Embedding source is [very new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.5#EmbeddedSource).  It will might happen for C++, some day.